# Creating multiple custom comparators for a dictionary based class

Tags: c#

I wish in my class to return a list from a dictionary but allow custom sorting using pre-written comparison methods. In my original java code that I'm converting from, I created compare methods using Google Guava Ordering in my class and then had a single method called the following passing in one of the public comparator methods, kind of declared like this:

```
public List<Word> getWords(Comparator c) { }
```

I'm trying to recreate this in C# but I can't figure out how. Essentially in the code below you can see there are three versions for each type of sort, and in addition I end up creating two lists for every return value which seems a bit wasteful.

I looked at creating delegates but got a bit lost, then figured I could create an IComparable, but then saw IComparator and then saw Sort method takes a Comparator.

Can somebody point me in the direction of converting this into a single sort 'GetWords' in the best way, allowing clients to call the GetWords retrieving a sorted list from a pre-supplied set of ordering.

```
public partial class WordTable
{
    private Dictionary<string, Word> words;

    public WordTable()
    {
        //for testing
        words = new Dictionary<string, Word>();
        words.Add("B", new Word("B", WordTypes.Adjective));
        words.Add("A", new Word("A", WordTypes.Noun));
        words.Add("D", new Word("D", WordTypes.Verb));
    }
    public List<Word> GetWords()
    {
        return words.Values.ToList();
    }
    public List<Word> GetWordsByName()
    {
        List<Word> list = words.Values.ToList<Word>();
        return list.OrderBy(word => word.Name).ToList();
    }
    public List<Word> GetWordsByType()
    {
        List<Word> list = words.Values.ToList<Word>();
        return list.OrderBy(word => word.Type).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that `Comparator` in several places in text or actually a `Comparer`?

Comment: I'm just mixing them in the assumption that you know I just want some kind of comparison function to pass in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you can use.

### IComparer

This is more closely related to your past Java experience.

The official way is to use `IComparer<T>` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Similar to your `Comparator` in the Java example, this enables you to create different sorting methods which all implement the `IComparer<Word>` interface, and then you can dynamically choose your sorting method.

As a simple example:

```
public class WordNameComparer : IComparer<Word>
{
    public int Compare(Word word1, Word word2)
    {
         return word1.Name.CompareTo(word2.Name);
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
public List<Word> GetWords(IComparer<Word> comparer)
{
    return words.Values.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).ToList();
}
```

Which you can call by doing:

```
var table = new WordTable();

List<Word> sortedWords = table.GetWords(new WordNameComparer());
```

And of course you change the sorting logic by passing a different `IComparer<Word>`.

---

### Func parameters

From experience, this is a much preferred approach due to LINQ's enhanced readability and low implementation cost.

Looking at your last two methods, you should see that the only variable part is the lambda method that you use to order the data. You can of course turn this variably into a method parameter:

```
public List<Word> GetWordsBy<T>(Func<Word,T> orderByPredicate)
{
    return words.Values.OrderBy(orderBy).ToList();
}
```

Because the `OrderBy` predicate uses a generic parameter for the selected property (e.g. sorting on a string field? an int field? ...), you have to make this method generic, but you don't need to explicitly use the generic parameter when you call the method. For example:

```
var sortedWordsByName =   table.GetWordsBy(w => w.Name);
var sortedWordsByLength = table.GetWordsBy(w => w.Name.Length);
var sortedWordsByType =   table.GetWordsBy(w => w.Type);
```

*Note that if you select a class, not a value type, that you will either still have to create and pass an `IComparer<>` for this class, or the class itself must implement [`IComparable<>`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/icomparable) so it can be sorted the way you want it to be.*

You can introduce ascending/descending ordering:

```
public List<Word> GetWordsBy<T>(Func<Word,T> orderByPredicate, bool sortAscending = true)
{
    return sortAscending
              ? words.Values.OrderBy(orderBy).ToList()
              ? words.Values.OrderByDescending(orderBy).ToList();
}
```

---

### Update

> I was trying to do it with delegates, but avoiding the caller having to roll their own lambda statement and use predefined ones.

You can simply wrap your method with some predefined options:

```
public List<Word> GetWordsBy<T>(Func<Word,T> orderByPredicate)
{
    return words.Values.OrderBy(orderBy).ToList();
}

public List<Word> GetWordsByName()
{
    return GetWordsBy(w => w.Name);
}
```

This way, your external callers don't need to use the lambda if they don't want to; but you still retain the benefits of having *reusable* code inside your class.

*There are many ways to do this. I prefer creating preset methods for readability's sake, but you could instead have an enum which you then map to the correct Func. Or you could create some static preset lambdas which the external caller can reference. Or... The world is your oyster :-)*

Comment: Thanks, the IComparer is a close comparison to the old java but the Func way was the kind way I was trying to do it with delegates, but avoiding the caller having to roll their own lambda statement and use predefined ones.

Comment: @NeilWalker: Nothing's stopping you from providing preset values. I'll update the answer with a small example.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [predicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Effectively, you want a predefined set of predicates (one for `ByName`, one for `ByType`), and you pass this predicate into the `GetWords` function.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works, or even compiles.

```
class WordTable
{
    public List<Word> GetWords(IComparer<Word> comparer)
    {
        return words.Values.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).ToList();
    }
}

class WordsByNameAndThenTypeComparer : IComparer<Word>
{
    public override int Compare(Word x, Word y)
    {
        int byName = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);

        return byName != 0 ? byName : x.Type.CompareTo(y.Type);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WordTable wt = new WordTable();
List<Words> words = wt.GetWords(new WordsByNameAndThenTypeComparer());
```

Comment: This isn't a guessing game. Don't post answers for which you don't even know they work or compile.

Comment: Please downvote only if you know for a fact that the answer is bad.

Comment: The answer does not provide any explanation while providing a less than trivial solution (you're introducing a whole new class `IComparer<T>`, not just fixing a syntax typo), and furthermore you're explicitly asserting that it might not even work/compile. Those are two valid reasons for considering this a bad answer.

Comment: The answer is not bad. It does compile. It does answer the question. But your answer is better.  Be kind.

Comment: The feedback on your answer is not in any way influenced by me having written an answer myself.

Comment: thanks. I get the gist of what you did, essentially similar to the previous thread using IComparer

Comment: @NeilWalker We usually expect "stable" results from functions, so that the same input always produces the same output. To that end we have to sort by all properties when sorting `Dictionary` values. So even if you use `Func` instead of `IComparer` you should sort by all properties in all cases.